# How can I get everything within a div using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to scrape a site that looks like this:

```
<div class="BOX">
  <div class="apple">This is an apple.</div>
  <p>Apple a day, doctor away</p>
</div>

<div class="BOX">
  <div class="iphone">This is an iPhone.</div>
  <div class="android">This is an Android.</div>
  <a href="www.apple.com">Apple home page</a>
  <p>Snoop Lion has both. He's rich.</p>
</div>
```

I would like to scrape everything within the "BOX" div. Each "BOX" has its own unique divs and HTML tags, with no apparent patterns. How would I do this?

My first attempt looked like this:

```
require 'uri-open'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.examplesite.com'))
doc.css('BOX').each do |box|
  puts box.content
end
```

But it returns nothing. May I please have an explanation of what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use [`#inner_html`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-inner_html) method instead of `#content`. Although your CSS [`class selector`](http://www.echoecho.com/cssselectors02.htm) rule is wrong. The code should look like below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eot
<div class="BOX">
  <div class="apple">This is an apple.</div>
  <p>Apple a day, doctor away</p>
</div>

<div class="BOX">
  <div class="iphone">This is an iPhone.</div>
  <div class="android">This is an Android.</div>
  <a href="www.apple.com">Apple home page</a>
  <p>Snoop Lion has both. Hes rich.</p>
</div>
eot

doc.css('.BOX').each do|n|
   p n.inner_html
end
```

**output:**

```
  <div class="apple">This is an apple.</div>
  <p>Apple a day, doctor away</p>

  <div class="iphone">This is an iPhone.</div>
  <div class="android">This is an Android.</div>
  <a href="www.apple.com">Apple home page</a>
  <p>Snoop Lion has both. He's rich.</p>
```

[`#content`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-content) will give you all the text by removing the html wrapper inside the each `div` node.See below :

```
doc.css('.BOX').each do|n|
   puts n.content
end
```

**output:**

```
  This is an apple.
  Apple a day, doctor away

  This is an iPhone.
  This is an Android.
  Apple home page
  Snoop Lion has both. He's rich.
```

Answer (score 4):

You missed a dot(`.`).

Without dot, it match a `<BOX>` tag. To match an element with `class="BOX"` you should prefix it with dot.

```
doc.css('.BOX').each do |box|
  #      ^-- here
  puts box.content
end
```

Comment: This is correct. Nokogiri's CSS selectors follow the same rules as normal HTML CSS selectors. `.foo` means the `CLASS` parameter for a tag, and `#foo` means the `ID` parameter for a tag. And, just like with normal CSS in a page, the CLASS selector can return multiple tags found within the DOM, whereas the ID selector will return the first. (Having multiple identical ID tags is a violation of the HTML spec so you shouldn't find more than one.)